# Mule ESB - http:outbound-endpoint no effect

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio

I have problem with flow defined like:

```
<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
    <flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="/home/fiscrm/Pulpit/pliki/tif" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" disableTransportTransformer="true"/>
        <file:file-to-byte-array-transformer ignoreBadInput="true" doc:name="File to Byte Array"/>
        <scripting:transformer ignoreBadInput="true" doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[println "TEST"
//
return [fileName: 'test', data: payload.encodeBase64().toString(), user: 'god', password:'god']]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="8080" path="invoice/document" method="POST" disableTransportTransformer="true" responseTimeout="1200000" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="binary/octet-stream"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Everything working fine when the input file is small. When I trying it on bigger file http request (outbound) have no data.

---

logs from server:

```
INFO  2013-04-25 08:15:57,525 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].File.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: /home/fiscrm/Pulpit/pliki/tif/dat-1-002.tif
INFO  2013-04-25 08:15:57,927 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2013-04-25 08:15:57,933 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.MuleMessageToHttpResponse
INFO  2013-04-25 08:15:57,965 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest
INFO  2013-04-25 08:15:57,966 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.2043296531'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-04-25 08:15:57,972 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.2043296531'. Object is: HttpClientMessageDispatcher
INFO  2013-04-25 08:15:58,016 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.http.transformers.ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest: Content-Type not set on outgoing request, defaulting to: text/plain
WARN  2013-04-25 08:15:58,673 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase: Going to buffer response body of large or unknown size. Using getResponseBodyAsStream instead is recommended.
ERROR 2013-04-25 08:15:58,673 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.http.HttpClientMessageDispatcher: [{"field":"user","message":"Property [user] of class [class pl.fissst.integration.mule.RecognizeAutoonlineDocumentCommand] cannot be null"},{"field":"password","message":"Property [password] of class [class pl.fissst.integration.mule.RecognizeAutoonlineDocumentCommand] cannot be null"},{"field":"fileName","message":"Property [fileName] of class [class pl.fissst.integration.mule.RecognizeAutoonlineDocumentCommand] cannot be null"}]
ERROR 2013-04-25 08:15:58,692 [[fisbps-aoutoonline].connector.http.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
```

Comment: And what do you have? An error? What do you see in the logs? How big is this bigger file?

Comment: I'm running it from Mule Studio. The effect is : when I drop small file, mule send to server defined in outbund correct request (with parameters from groovy script. But when when I drop big file the request is going to server but without any parameters.

Comment: How big is the file when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a reason where the size of the file is too big and the time for reading file is less and only little or half of the file.

For this you need to use the "file age" attribute for the file endpoint .

Please follow the below link which has the details of the file age

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/File+Endpoint+Reference